# How to show array values in different forms?

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I need to implement such form

[image]

I get json data from server:

```
"category_attributes": [
    [
        {
            "name": "IPhone",
            "terms": [
                {
                    "name": "iPhone 11"
                },
                {
                    "name": "iPhone 12"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "Memory",
            "terms": [
                {
                    "name": "1024"
                },
                {
                    "name": "128"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]

struct EachCategory: Decodable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let category_attributes: [[CategoriesAttributes]]
}

struct CategoriesAttributes: Decodable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let terms: [CateroriesTerms]
}

struct CateroriesTerms: Decodable, Hashable {
    let name: String
}
```

I need to show first object's values of terms array inside buttons, and memory in dropdown list. I can only show all array values in buttons https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Dib.jpg How can I show only first object in buttons, and other objects in different form?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(viewModel.categoryAttributes, id: \.self) { category in
                    ForEach(category, id: \.self) { attribute in
                    Text(attribute.name)
                    HStack {
                    ForEach(attribute.terms, id: \.self) { term in
                    Button {
                        print("Phone model is selected")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(term.name)")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.textFieldGrayColor)
                    }.background(Color.grayButton)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid. It would be more helpful to see the data model that the JSON was decoded into.

Comment: @Yrb added JSON model

Comment: I hate JSON like that. Part of your problem is this: `let category_attributes: [[CategoriesAttributes]]`. You have an array of array. So, when you try: `ForEach(viewModel.categoryAttributes, id: \.self)` your `category` is not a `CategoriesAttributes`, it is an `[CategoriesAttributes]`. You need to unwind that in your view model so your `viewModel.categoryAttributes` starts out as an `[CategoriesAttributes]` and therefore `category` would be a `CategoriesAttributes`.

Comment: Thank you, changed, now it's looks better https://imgur.com/a/bm0bWjR Could you please give a tip, how can I show only first object of array in buttons, and others in any form?

Comment: Again, that seems like model logic. It appears that the JSON response is a list of device types, then a list of memory types. So, inn your model it would be something like var deviceModels = categoryAttributes.first(where: { $0.name == "iPhone" }. This will return an optional as their may be no match.